# download list of url csv files python IOError: [Errno 22]

Tags: python, csv, url

I have the following code below. [Credit to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173372/download-files-from-a-list-if-not-already-downloaded) I keep getting an error before it downloads any of the csv files. USW00000100.csv is the first csv file name. I'm not sure why I am getting the error. There doesn't seem to be any unsupported characters in my filename.

```
import os
import urllib

DOWNLOADS_DIR = "C:/py-testing/downloads"

# For every line in the file
for url in open("C:/py-testing/urls.txt"):
    # Split on the rightmost / and take everything on the right side of that
    name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

    # Combine the name and the downloads directory to get the local filename
    filename = os.path.join(DOWNLOADS_DIR, name)
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Error:

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:/py-testing/downloads\USW00000100.csv\n'

Comment: strip the \n from name

Comment: If I do 'print filename' it displays without the \n though. C:/py-testing/downloads\USW00000100.csv.  I will try it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably the newline at the end of the filename. When you read the line in from the CSV, it's including the newline. There's a couple of ways you can handle this.

You can simply strip the newline from the end like so.

```
raw_name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
name = raw_name.strip()
# your code here
```

Another way, with a terser functional style (thanks @fenceop)

```
for url in map(str.strip, file): 
    # your code here
```